# Determine if a matrix is square OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm working on a problem where they ask us to write a function to determine if a matrix is square (n by n, for any n >= 0) with OCaml
I have a type matrix already defined

```
type matrix = float list list
```

Also I previously have a function that works to determine the length of a list

```
let rec length (l : 'a list): int =  
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | _ :: xs' -> 1 + length xs'
```

Right now I'm thinking about writing a helper function which checks if the length of all rows are equal

```
let rec check_row_equal (m : matrix): bool =
  match m with
  | [] -> true
  | h1 :: h2 :: t -> 
    if length h1 <> length h2 then false
    else check_row_equal (h2 :: t)
```

But when I ran this function in utop, it says `Match_failure ("//toplevel//", 2, 2)`. If I have this helper function running correctly, my thought for my next function would be

```
let rec is_square (m : matrix): bool =
  let l = length m in
  if check_row_equal m == false then false
  else if (l != the length of one of the rows) then false
  else true
```

I haven't figured out how to calculate the length of the row, maybe another helper function like

```
let row_length (m : matrix): int =
  match m with
  | [] -> 0
  | h :: t -> length h
```

But again, I need help with the `check_row_equal` function, please help me to fix that, thank u!

Comment: I modified the length function so it works for the normal kind of list: `let rec length (l : 'a list): int = match l with | [] -> 0 | _ :: xs' -> 1 + length xs'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> let rec check_row_equal (m : matrix): bool =
>   match m with
>   | [] -> true
>   | h1 :: h2 :: t -> 
>     if length h1 <> length h2 then false
>     else check_row_equal (h2 :: t)
> ```

You're getting a match error because you have a case for an empty list, and a list with two or more elements, but *not* a list with one element.  Presumably if there is only one row, this should return `true`.

Incorporating this and simplifying the code a bit.

```
let rec check_row_equal (m : matrix): bool =
  match m with
  | [] | [_] -> true
  | h1 :: (h2 :: _ as tl) -> 
    length h1 = length h2 && check_row_equal tl
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what it means specifically to check whether a matrix is square. I'll assume you want to check the lengths of all the contained lists to make sure they're the same, and this should also be the same as the length of the outer list.

Here are a couple of comments:

1. Your `length` function works correctly in the abstract, but it doesn't work for the normal kind of OCaml list. In OCaml, the empty list (the final tail of every list) looks like `[]` and `Cons (a, b)` looks like `a :: b`. Maybe your code is supposed to work with a custom list type, but then it's confusing to name it `list`, like the normal OCaml list.
2. You already have a function `length` that visits every element of a list and calculates an answer. You need a function just like this except that each element of the list is another list, and you want to determine whether the lengths of these are all the same. Just as your `length` function gets a new result by adding 1 to the returned result, you can figure out an operation that tracks whether the lists have all been the same length so far and, if so, what that length was.

I hope this helps. I don't want to write code for you because this is an assignment.